# What makes the iPhone video encryption so tough?

Tags: iphone, applications, security

It seems that there isn't a single iPhone app that does video encryption.

There are a lot of "privacy" apps that "protect" videos and photos with a password and without encryption and there are some apps that actually do AES encryption of photos, but absolutely none that would do the AES encryption of videos.

Why might this be? Is it performance or resource related?

Comment: Don't add an answer to your question via editing; submit it as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is a rant. Please do not post rants on this site, but focus on what you want to achieve. I've edited your post so it isn't a rant. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Two explanations:

- Video files are significantly bigger than your usual iPhone picture -> encryption would take a very long time
- No real need (aka market)

Comment: I'm inclined to think its heavily to do with the second bullet point myself. Also on the first point, would take a lot of space.